# How to bypass Spring security filter for all file in i18n folder

Tags: spring, security

I defined springSecurityFilterChain in Web.xml

> ```
>     <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
>     <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
> </filter>
> <filter-mapping>
>   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
>    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>       
> </filter-mapping>
> ```

And in security file (security-config-cas.xml). I definded bypass as below:

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/i18n/**"
                filters="none" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

My application is deploying on Websphere...It seems this configuration is not working because there is still below exception output when run application.

[4/11/14 10:27:32:993 EDT] 00000e71 filter        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper doFilter SRVE8109W: Uncaught exception thrown by filter springSecurityFilterChain: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /i18n/messages_en-us.properties
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:700)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.csc.fsg.pcdSecurity.filter.CASFilter.doFilter(CASFilter.java:663)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:975)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1815)

I tried another way as

> ```
> <bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
>     <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
>       <security:filter-chain pattern="/i18n/**" filters="none"/>
>     </security:filter-chain-map>
> </bean> <alias name="filterChainProxy" alias="springSecurityFilterChain"/>
> ```

But my project is not working when I added alias.. log in to home page and it is loading so long.... If I am missing any configuration?

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You probalby can use something like

```
<http pattern="/your-folder/**" secure="none">
</http>
```

Or use intercept-url ( on spring-servlet.xml )

```
<intercept-url pattern="/your-folder/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
```

Depending on how you are using Spring, maybe you need to add the following to dispatcher-servelt.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/your-folder/**" location="/your-folder/" />
```

Comment: I already added <security:http pattern="/i18n/**" security="none"/>  in my security file before.. but spring security still did filter on i18n folder.

Comment: Hmmm.... bizarre... maybe the cause of this is the configuration that you added in the security-config-cas.xml fiel. Just for curiosity, take a look at this sample application:
 https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-social-examples/blob/master/sign-in/spring-mvc-normal/src/main/resources/exampleApplicationContext-security.xml